# Setting index of SelectedListItem razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am populating a dropdown using as

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please make a selection")]
    public string SelectedPrimary { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PrimaryDrop { get; set; }

public void populateDropdown()
    {
        primaryDrop = new List<string>();
        primaryDrop.Insert(0, "Getting ready");
        primaryDrop.Insert(1, "Starting");
        primaryDrop.Insert(2, "All");
        PrimaryDrop = primaryDrop.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Value = item, Text = item });
    }
```

And then my razor view is as follow

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPrimary, new SelectList(Model.PrimaryDrop, "Value", "Text"), "Learning Path", new { style = "width:207px;", id = "FirstDropDown" })
```

Upon inspecting the element I would see this

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="Please make a selection" id="FirstDropDown" name="SelectedPrimary" style="width:207px;">
     <option value="">Learning Path</option>
     <option value="Getting ready">Getting ready</option>
     <option value="Starting">Starting</option>
   <option value="All modules">All</option>
    </select>
```

How could I go about in setting the values to the index ?

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="Please make a selection" id="FirstDropDown" name="SelectedPrimary" style="width:207px;">
     <option value="0">Learning Path</option>
     <option value="1">Getting ready</option>
     <option value="2">Starting</option>
   <option value="3">All modules</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a Dictionary to build the SelectList.  Then use key as the value and value as the text

```
var primaryDrop = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
            {"0", "Getting Ready"},
            {"1", "Starting"},
            {"2", "All"}            
        };
PrimaryDrop = primaryDrop.Select(item => 
    new SelectListItem { Value = item.Key, Text = item.Value });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fill `PrimaryDrop` like this (using [`List<T>.IndexOf(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) to get `Value`)

```
primaryDrop = new List<string>();
primaryDrop.Insert(0, "Getting ready");
primaryDrop.Insert(1, "Starting");
primaryDrop.Insert(2, "All");
PrimaryDrop = primaryDrop.Select(item => new SelectListItem 
{ 
    Value = primaryDrop.IndexOf(item), 
    Text = item 
});
```